# Can't link static library on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, static-libraries

I can't link static libraries to executable file on Mac OS X.
I have in my repo directory `lib` witch contains all of libraries such as `libstdc++.a`, `libssl.a`, `libz.a`.
CMakeList.txt contains:

```
(...)
set(PROJECT_LINK_LIBS libcurl.a libz.a libssl.a libcrypto.a libstdc++.a libjson-c.a)
link_directories(lib/)
add_executable(myapp ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(myapp ${PROJECT_LINK_LIBS} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
```

While compiling I got a messages (for each `.a` file):

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/kuba/CLionProjects/RigService/lib/macos/libz.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

and:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_curl_easy_cleanup", referenced from:
        HTTPConnection::request(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, char const*) in HTTPConnection.cpp.o
    "_curl_easy_init", referenced from:
        HTTPConnection::request(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, char const*) in HTTPConnection.cpp.o
    "_curl_easy_perform", referenced from:
        HTTPConnection::request(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, char const*) in HTTPConnection.cpp.o
(...)
```

I have compilate this on a linux before, and there I didn't have any problem.
I was tring to extract all `.o` files from `.a` and again build a archive file using

```
ar rcs libcurl.a *.o
```

but after it I got the same problem.
I was also trying to build a archive via

```
libtool -static -o libcurl.a *.o
```

but then I got a message:

```
sal:libcrypto kuba$ libtool -static -o libcrypto.a *.o
error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: file: a_bitstr.o is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: file: a_bool.o is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: file: a_bytes.o is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
(...) // error for each .o file
```

And here is my question, maybe should I start from it, **can I link the same `.a` files while compilating on linux and mac os?**

Comment: Are the object files extracted really MacOS object files? It seems that you are trying to build a MacOS library with Linux object files (which is obviously wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use libraries built for Linux? That won't work, you need libraries built for macOS.

Comment: Will work program compilated on macOS, with a libraries for macOS, on a linux?

Comment: No. You need macOS libraries on macOS and you need Linux libraries on Linux.

Comment: Tell me one more thing, please. Can I compile a program on macOS with libraries for Linux to run it on Linux?

Comment: Not with the standard compiler and toolchain.

You can install a cross compiler and toolchain, but it's probably easier to set up a virtual machine that runs Linux and use that to build for Linux.